# enable vbscript in internet explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

In a website vbscript is not opening in the higher version of browsers. Actually the website is containing the scripting in VB script. when the website is being opened in Internet Explorer 9 then it is not supporting the scripting and giving the following error

```
javascript:void(0)
```

but the files are opening in internet explorer 8. so can you suggest how to enable the scripting in browser.

Comment: Is there a website with scripting in VBScript??? Wow, in the World we can really see everything...

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error. VBScript is still supported in IE 9.